# MYSQL - Storing lots of text fields in a single row

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to PHP/MYSQL, I have a website which has multiple long forms, and more are added on a regular basis. The data from all the forms is stored in a 'data' MYSQL table.

The way I approached storing the data was to have 200 text columns (as my forms are up to 200 questions long). Not every question needs a text column, about 50% are just single integers or a few word answers, but as they vary in order this was the simplest way I could think of to make it work.

I've now discovered I can't seem to store more than 10 text values in a single row as I get the following error:

Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to `TEXT` or `BLOB` or using `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` or `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` may help. In current row format, `BLOB` prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

Where am I going wrong and what's the best way to store data like this? I know 200 columns seems a lot and I've read this must mean I haven't normalised my data properly, but creating lots of tables doesn't seem to be sensible in this case, as all the data is connected on a single level to the form it came from. Splitting it in to 20 tables with data `1-10 11-20 21-30` just doesn't seem right?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should have each question saved as row, and in each row have column name f.e. id_field... Then your table will not have 200 columns, but only couple (depends on other columns in your table)...

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, just hadn't thought of it this way, there's no reason why all the answers need to be in one row! Lightbulb moment!

Comment: I just added it also as a answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create a table where each field is a separate row:

```
CREATE TABLE Question_Fields (
    question_id INT, -- FK to Question table
    field_num INT,
    field_value VARCHAR(1024)
);
```

You can then join this table with the `Question` table to get all the text fields for that question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would this mean I'd need a new table for every set of data? The forms will be filled in 100's of times.

Comment: No, you just need this one table. All you're doing is moving all those text columns out of the questions table, and into rows in this table. The foreign key links them back to the original row in the questions table.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case in which you should consider NoSQL. You don't have a fixed schema.
Consider using [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) [<sup>Tutorial</sup>](http://php.net/manual/it/mongo.tutorial.php)

```
// connect
$m = new MongoClient();

// select a database
$db = $m->comedy;

// select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
$collection = $db->cartoons;

// add a record
$document = array( "title" => "Calvin and Hobbes", "author" => "Bill Watterson" );
$collection->insert($document);

// add another record, with a different "shape"
$document = array( "title" => "XKCD", "online" => true );
$collection->insert($document);

// find everything in the collection
$cursor = $collection->find();

// iterate through the results
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    echo $document["title"] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have each question saved as row, and in each row have column name f.e. id_field... Then your table will not have 200 columns, but only couple (depends on other columns in your table)...